# Unauthenticated in Laravel JWT authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I used [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth).

It works well in login, but when I try to register it and go through the login request the error below occurred.

> "message": "Unauthenticated."

Here is the source code:

**config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => True,
    ],
```

**routes/api.php:**

```
Route::group([    
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',//must include the path
    'prefix' => 'auth'
    
    ], function ($router) {
    
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');

    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');
    
});
```

**AuthController.php**

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login,signup']]);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    public function signup(Request $request){
        $validation = $request->validate([
            'email' =>'required',
            'name' =>'required',
            'password'=>'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        $data = array();
        $data['name'] = $request->name;
        $data['email'] = $request->email;
        $data['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
        DB::table('users')->insert($data);
        return $this->login($request);     
       
    }
```

I provided **DB** and **Hash** classes. In postman, I put the route in the **POST** method and set headers `Accept` and `content-type` as `application/json` formate and in the body part, I set `x-www-form` and input all the keys and values with confirmation_password key. It not inserting into the database and showing the error message. I tried it by clearing the config cache and route cache. I also tried it with raw and json format.

Comment: Are you sure the user was saved in the database in registration?

Comment: The user data didn't saved in the users table. I am trying to register it by post api

Comment: Please share your user's table columns and check the Laravel logs file on register

Comment: @enamulhaque I'd suggest enabling error logging within your env file, after which you will know which middleware triggered Unauthenticated error.

Comment: Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps(); This is user's table column

Comment: @Vlad Vladimir Hercules thanks. I removed the construct function from authcontroller.
Now it works. But why it doesn't work with it?

Comment: @enamulhaque I dont know. I'd try debugging code first. The signup method can be refactored to identify where the issue is. For example, you  can take validation into FormRequest class, DB::insert can be wrapped into a db transaction and similar. I am happy to create an example code if you like.

Answer (score 1):

i think you problem with ur constractor  middleware u didn't make the except value right  u have to make to different values for except  like that

```php
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login','signup']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use create or save Method to store the new user. After you store user in your database you can generate a usertoken and send him back. And the user is logged in. Every further request is then regulated via the token.

```
        $token = // generate an new token with the JWT toker Helper method ;
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'ok',
            'token' => $token,
            'user' => $user
        ], 201);
```

Comment: @Mahmoud Hazem thanks , It helps me lot

Comment: @enamulhaque With pleasure! ;-) if it helps you you can vote up or accept this answear.